# My Excel formula doesn't work, i used SUMIF IN Excel 365

Tags: excel, excel-formula

i need help about excel formula, i used sumif to calculate cost per years.
=SUMIF(D2:D66,B2,E2:E66) this formula result is =  34,989,822 ( wrong )
the result should be =  532,903,030

can you fix my formula ?
please help [screenshoot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TUG2c.png)

Comment: You're just getting the single value for 2055, which is the only row that matches B2. Which rows do you need to select?

Comment: i mean if 2055 enter then sum of 2022 - 2055 = 532,903,030

Comment: Did you specify the range correctly in your question? as in a comment you change the range from E2:E66 to E2:E67 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i am using different language formulas in Excel. But it has to be like this;

```
=SUMIF(D2:D66,"<="&B2 ,E2:E66)
```

According to my language (Summing up the area until B2 cell value);

```
=ETOPLA(D2:D66;"<="&B2;E2:E66)
```

Comment: thanks for your answer , 
the formula should be 
=SUMIF(D2:D67,"<="&B2,E2:E67)

Comment: That's correct. The criteria is important :)